# Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0] - LARAVEL / XAMPP / PHP7

Tags: laravel, email, xampp, gmail, php-7

I can't send any email in my local XAMMP server.

I am using LARAVEL with XAMPP server and PHP7.

When I click on button, the message is:

```
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0]
```

my .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypass
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

I have tried port 587 but also didn't work. It's a local problem?

With this config on my hosting maybe works?

Comment: Please try to add next line to your hosts file: `74.125.136.109 smtp.gmail.com` to check whether it is IPv6 issue or not.

Comment: returns me the same error: Connection could not be established with host 74.125.136.109 [ #0]

Comment: O.K. Then please remove that line in hosts file and change your laravel mail settings to encryption=tls port=587

Comment: returns me: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

Comment: okidoki, try to follow what this guy says on this Laracasts [thread](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/error-sendmail-using-laravel-xampp-php-7-windows/replies/180810)

Answer (score 0):

Update the driver to sendmail in your `.env` file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
```

Comment: If I change this, the error is: 
Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 298:
Process could not be started [The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: The gmail account you are using for connect is two factor authenticated?

Comment: xampp\php\php.ini open it and tell me what is sendmail_path set to?

Comment: to nothing: ;sendmail_path =

Comment: Are you on windows or macos?

Comment: Okay update the sendmail line with sendmail_path="\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t" also check your path is that how you put up your xammp folder. And then in your  C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini. Put up your details

Comment: I made exactly all that you tell me, but still show me the same error: Process could not be started [The system cannot find the path specified. 
This error is driving me crazy!

Comment: have your update your laravel's config/mail.php too?

Comment: @frcam i also test this and successfully send an email. this is my env settings MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl

and i started my server through terminal command `php artisan serve`

Comment: Change your settings according to my above comment and tell me what you get in error

Comment: my configs are like this, and the error is the same at the inicial: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0]

Comment: When you update your .env file. you've to restart your server. are you doing this? and i suggest you to start your project with command line using `php artisan serve` command and open your project in `localhost:8000`. Are you using this flow?

Comment: Yeah, i'm using this flow. And always that I edit my .env file I do with server off. I don't know whats up, maybe in a web hosting it works.. I will try.

Answer (score 0):

1: Either you must allow less secure apps or use app password by enabling 2 step verification on your gmail acc.
2: Disable any antivirus on your machine.
3: Don't forget to clear your cache (sometimes it don't take updated content from .env file)
4: You don't need to change anything in Mailer inside config directory(not recommended), you should use env variables